# Triggers: Tracking ID Updates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-update

For a trigger that is tracking UPDATEs to a table, two temp tables may be referenced: deleted and inserted.  Is there a way to cross-reference the two w/o using an INNER JOIN on their primary key?

I am trying to maintain referential integrity without foreign keys (don't ask), so I'm using triggers.  I want UPDATEs to the primary key in table A to be reflected in the "foreign key" of look-up table B, and for this to happen when an UPDATE affects multiple records in table A.

All UPDATE trigger examples that I've seen hinge on joining the inserted and deleted tables to track changes; and they use the updated table's ID field (primary key) to set the join.  But if that ID field (GUID) is the changed field in a record (or set of records), is there a good way to track those changes, so that I can enforce those changes in the corresponding look-up table?

Comment: Why would you be updating the primary key? How else do you expect identify the row that you changed, before and after you make such a change?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't a clue. I'm updating an app that's a bit all over the place in it's logic.  I'm trying to future-proof (read: idiot-proof) this trigger, so that no one, down the road, orphans a whole set of records accidentally.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just had this issue (or rather, a similar one), myself, hence the resurrection...

My eventual approach was to simply disallow updates to the PK field precisely because it would break the trigger.  Thankfully, I had no business case to support updating the primary key column (these were surrogate IDs, anyway), so I could get away with it.

SQL Server offers the `UPDATE` function, for use within triggers, to check for this edge case:

```
CREATE TRIGGER your_trigger
ON your_table
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS BEGIN

    IF UPDATE(pk1) BEGIN
        ROLLBACK

        DECLARE @proc SYSNAME, @table SYSNAME

        SELECT TOP 1
             @proc = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
            ,@table = OBJECT_NAME(parent_id)
        FROM sys.triggers 
        WHERE object_id = @@PROCID

        RAISERROR ('Trigger %s prevents UPDATE of table %s due to locked primary key', 16, -1, @proc, @table) WITH NOWAIT
    END
    ELSE UPDATE t SET
         col1 = i.col1
        ,col2 = i.col2
        ,col3 = i.col3
    FROM your_table t
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON t.pk1 = i.pk1

END
GO
```

*(Note that the above is untested, and probably contains all manner of issues with regards to `XACT_STATE` or `TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL` -- it's just there to demonstrate the principle)*

It gets a bit messy, though, so I would definitely consider code generation for this, to handle changes to the table during development (maybe even done by a DDL trigger on CREATE/ALTER table).

If you have a composite primary key, you can use `IF UPDATE(pk1) OR UPDATE(pk2)...` or do some bitwise work with the `COLUMNS_UPDATED` function, which will give you a bitmask based on the column ordinal (but I'm not going to cover that here -- see MSDN/BOL).

The other (simpler) option is to `DENY UPDATE ON your_table(pk) TO public`, but remember that any member of `sysadmins` (and probably `dbo`) will *not* honour this.

Comment: this is the most complete, well-thoughtout answer I've ever received on StackOverflow.  Very much appreciated.    

I honestly don't trust the application that's updating these tables _not_ to do something stupid like create a new GUID for an existing record.  And there's just too many lines of code to audit every query.  That said, the app has to be able to create new GUIDs for new records.  So, this is elegant & quick solution that bubbles up just the way you'd want it to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm with @Aaron, without a primary key you're stuck. If you have DDL privileges to add a trigger can't you add a auto increment PK column while you're at it?  If you'd like, it doesn't even need to be the PK.